# ngStyle is applied only after F5 (refresh)

Tags: angular

In my angular project I have this line in one of my component html

```
...
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': grayedOut ? '#999999' : '#ffffff'}">
...
```

where grayedOut is defined as an input in the my-component.ts file like so :

```
...
@Input() grayedOut: boolean;
...
```

I then instanciate my component in a view component html like this :

```
...
<app-my-component [grayedOut]=true ></app-my-component>
...
```

But it's never working on the first load, I have to press F5 for the gray style to apply.
What am I doing wrong ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try , `[grayedOut]="true"`; or just define a variable in your component as `bool = true` and use it like `[grayedOut]="bool"`. If this dones't work are you using any changedetection strategy in your child component ?

Comment: I made a playground for this issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-elgosy .
It seems to work fine!

Comment: Well indeed it works, after hours of trying different things it seems it was just a cache problem. I did try ctrl+F5 on the view page where is my component without success. It seems that I needed to ctrl+F5 on the root page of my project. Now it works on first load. I'm curious as to why I needed to ctrl+F5 on the root tho. Thank you guys, sorry to have wasted your time.